# Filter entities on mapping level in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Let's say that I have and database table called People, and entity People. Let's say that I need a quick way to remove a subset of people from displaying everywhere in application. So I add IsDeleted column to People table, and set values in that column to 1.

In Entity Framework there's a mechanism that specifies that for instans of entities with value in column IsDeleted set to 1 shouldn't be fetched and mapping framework filters data automatically. Is is possible to achieve with NHibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create abstract class, e.g. `PeopleBase`, from which your `People` class will be derived and map your entity to it.
After that you can use discriminator like this (didn't check for correctness, but it should work):

```
 <class name="YourNamespace.PeopleBase,YourNamespace" table="People">
   // ...
   <discriminator column="IsDeleted" type="boolean" /> 
   // Properties...
   // ...
   <subclass name="YourNamespace.People, YourNamespace" discriminator-value="false">
   </subclass>
</class>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can define `where` attribute in your [class mapping](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-class).

> ***where*** (optional) specify an arbitrary SQL WHERE condition to be used
>   when retrieving objects of this class

```
<class ... where="IsDeleted = 0">
```

If you are using Fluent NHibernate then just define this in mapping class:

```
Where("IsDeleted = 0");
```

NH's mapping by code should be similar to Fluent NHibernate's mapping.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what I wanted, I've created base class + two subclasses. This is the configuration:

- subclasses with **discriminator-value**:

  ```
  <subclass name="People" discriminator-value="null">
  </subclass>
  <subclass name="PeopleHistory" discriminator-value="not null">
      <property name="MasterRowId" />
  </subclass>
  ```
- discriminator in base **class**:

  ```
  <discriminator column="MasterRowId" />
  ```