# NHibernate mapping to existing database schema: don't know exactly how to solve?

Tags: xml, nhibernate, mapping, many-to-one, discriminator

The situation is as follows:

I have a Oracle database where the database schema is given, so I can't change this. IDs are generated through the database and are the primary keys. The OR-mapper is a self-written one and I have to replace it with NHibernate.

I have two tables that have only an association and no inheritance:

1. **ModeType**: ID, Name, Origin
2. **Mode**: ID, Mode_Type_ID, Comment

The classes I have are as follows:

1. **ModeType**: public properties: ID, Name, Origin
2. **ModeProduction**: public properties: ID, ModeType_ID, Comment
3. **ModeQualityCheck**: public properties: ID, ModeType_ID, Comment

With the "old" OR-mapper the classes **ModeProduction** and **ModeQualityCheck** are persisted to the table **Mode**. For example you want to retrieve (and then write back) all **ModeProducts**, the **ModeProducts** are taken from the table **Mode** where the "ModeType_ID" is equal to the "ID" in the **ModeType** table with "Origin" = 1. The property/column "Origin" acts like a discriminator, but without inheritance.

So, how can I map this in NHibernate to have the same effect: get all **ModeProducts** (and write them back later), where Origin is 1 in the **ModeType** table?

I have the following XML-mappings so far:

**ModeType:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                     assembly="Domain"
                     namespace="Domain.Domain">
    <class name="ModeTypeBase" table="MODE_TYPES">
      <id name="Id" column="ID" access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore">
        <generator class="sequence">
          <param name="sequence">MODE_TYPES_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
      </id>
      <property name="Name" column="NAME" not-null="true" />
      <property name="Origin" column="ORIGIN" not-null="true" />
    </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
```

**ModeProduction:** (Origin = 1 in table **ModeType**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Domain"
                   namespace="Domain.Domain">
  <class name="ModeProduction" table="MODES">
    <id name="Id" column="ID" access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">MODES_SEQ</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Comment" column="COMMENT" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="ModeTypeObject" class="ModeType" column="MODE_TYPE_ID" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**ModeQualityCheck:** (Origin = 0 in table **ModeType**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Domain"
                   namespace="Domain.Domain">
  <class name="ModeQualityCheck" table="MODES">
    <id name="Id" column="ID" access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">MODES_SEQ</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Comment" column="COMMENT" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="ModeTypeObject" class="ModeType" column="MODE_TYPE_ID" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Can someone help me out, please?

Comment: maybe you can try adding a _where_ attribute in your class mapping, see : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10905329/1236044

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Somehow I read it over. But I think, this is not an option for my problem, because using "where" would end up in only one class, I think, and I need two different classes, like ModeTypeProduction and ModeTypeQualityCheck. Now, I changed my class-hierarchy, like the problem-poster of your link did. ;) That's the best option I have right now. ;)